# Make Alexa Announce the notification through a custom skill by calling any APIs from Backend without saying 'Alexa Read my notifications'?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-notification

I am building a custom skills for one of my use case. I am trying to implement a feature based on a token number. If token number 2 got his order, I want Alexa to announce about the next token number. Let's say for example, 'Token Number 3, your order is ready'. I would like to know that, is there any way for me to let Alexa know about these events? Is there any API which I could call to make Alexa announce only for that specific device.

I came across few things like AVS Notifications, Alexa SDNS, Alexa Senior Living Notifications API in the Alexa documentation. I've tried reading through documentations and watched videos but couldn't find anything useful for my purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it yet.

What you can do now is send a [push notification](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/response-api/alexa-for-apps/s2p) to the mobile device (developer preview)

Comment: As I have mentioned in my title, I would like a way for the alexa to announce the notifications without having the user to say "Alexa Read my notifications" and I know proactive events does not support this.

Comment: There is no way to do it yet